# If $X_n$ are symmetric around $0$ then show $P(|S_n|\geq\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, symmetry, independence

> Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be iid random variables that are symmetric around $0$ i.e. $X=-X$ in distribution. Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then show $P(|S_n|\geq\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$.

I believe we would need some nice inequality for this. The first thing that comes to my mind is Kolmogorov's inequality but I am not sure.

Comment: The trick here is to use some symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_i = |X_i|$, and let $s_i$ be chosen randomly for $\{\pm 1\}$. The variables $Y_i$ are iid and have a certain distribution. One way of generating the $X_i$ is generating the $Y_i$ and $s_i$, and using the formula $X_i = s_i Y_i$.

We will show that for every $y_1,\ldots,y_n$,
$$
P(|S_n| \geq \max_i y_i \; | \; \vec{Y} = \vec{y}) \geq 1/2,
$$
which implies your statement. We can assume without loss of generality that $Y_1 \geq Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$, and further condition on the value of $s_1$, which we assume without loss of generality is $s_1 = 1$. Under this conditioning, we prove an even stronger statement:
$$
P(S_n \geq y_1 \; \vec{Y} = \vec{y}, s_1=1) \geq 1/2.
$$

In order to prove the latter statement, we consider a different way of generating the remaining signs $s_2,\ldots,s_n$. We first choose $n$ random signs $t_2,\ldots,t_n,u$, and then take $s_2 = ut_2,\ldots,s_n = ut_n$; this results in the same distribution. Taking $Z = \sum_{i=2}^n t_i y_i$, we note that
$$ S_n = y_1 + uZ. $$
If $Z = 0$ then $P(S_n \geq y_1) = 1$. If $Z > 0$ then $P(S_n \geq y_1) = P(u=1) = 1/2$. If $Z < 0$ then $P(S_n \geq y_1) = P(u=-1) = 1/2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: I really like your answer. Could you please share the motivation? It seems too beautiful.

Comment: It's a rather standard trick that arises when dealing with symmetric variables. Generally speaking, after you've read many proofs, you will know most of the standard trick, and will be able to use them when necessary.